# mySQL keeps switching column and argument

Tags: mysql

Trying to run a query, keep getting `ERROR 1054`:

```
SELECT *
    from my_table
    WHERE 1=1
    AND MYCITY = CHICAGO
;
```

Now, I use `WHERE 1=1` and `AND` because I'm running multiple arguments.  This is the only argument that clods everything up.  The error is reads in its entirety:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'CHICAGO' in 'where class'
```

It's looking for column `CHICAGO` instead of the value `CHICAGO` in column `MYCITY` and I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to quote your string value

```
SELECT *
    from my_table
    WHERE 1=1
    AND MYCITY = 'CHICAGO'
;
```

Comment: Any clue how to make that fly in a PHP statement?  `AND ".$db->nameQuote('MYCITY')." = ".$db->quote($city)."`

Comment: Yep: `AND ".$db->nameQuote('MYCITY')." = '".$db->quote($city)."'"`